# Can I render my Infragistics UltraWinGrid Column-headers at ninety-degrees?

Tags: vb.net, formatting, ultrawingrid

I have lots of thin columns in a table that I use Infragistics UltraWinGrid to render.

Can I display the column headers at ninety degrees so that they can be quite long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noggins,

Yes, you could display your headers in such way. Below you could find three possibilities for rotating your headers and you should choose the one that suits your needs best. I am handling the InitializeLayout event of the UltraGrid control like the following:

```
`    Private Sub UltraGrid1_InitializeLayout(sender As System.Object, e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs) Handles UltraGrid1.InitializeLayout
    'Create your own Vertical Orientation (1)
    e.Layout.Override.ColumnHeaderTextOrientation = New Infragistics.Win.TextOrientationInfo(0, Infragistics.Win.TextFlowDirection.Vertical)
    'Create your own Horizontal Orientation, rotating the headers (2)
    e.Layout.Override.ColumnHeaderTextOrientation = New Infragistics.Win.TextOrientationInfo(90, Infragistics.Win.TextFlowDirection.Horizontal)
    'Create your own Horizontal Orientation, rotating the headers into the opposite direction (3)
    e.Layout.Override.ColumnHeaderTextOrientation = New Infragistics.Win.TextOrientationInfo(-90, Infragistics.Win.TextFlowDirection.Horizontal)
End Sub`
```